# How can i check string contains unknown character?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am calling webservice in the response i am getting the string.
When i print the string in NSLog it return empty string  and When i check the length it returns 1.

So my problem is that how can i check the string is empty or not.

```
#define CHECK_NA_STRING(str) (str == (id)[NSNull null] || [str length] == 0)?@"N/A":str

NSLog(@"%@",CHECK_NA_STRING([dict objectForKey:@"ADDRESS_A"]));  // nothing empty string
NSLog(@"%d",[CHECK_NA_STRING([dict objectForKey:@"ADDRESS_A"]) length]); // return 1
```

So how can i check that string is empty or not?
Thanks.

Comment: ok yes it contains one space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the string is just a space? Then it will still have a length of 1.

Try:

```
NSString* string = ...;

if([string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    NSCharacterSet* invertedWhitespaceSet = [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] invertedSet];

    const NSRange nonEmptyCharacterRange = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:invertedWhitespaceSet options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];  

    if(nonEmptyCharacterRange.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        //  Empty invalid string    
    }
    else
    {
        //  Non-empty valid string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string is not considered empty if it contains a binary zero (null character).  For instance, try this code:

```
#define CHECK_NA_STRING(str) (str == (id)[NSNull null] || [str length] == 0)?@"N/A":str
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:@"\0" forKey:@"ADDRESS_A"];
NSLog(@"%@",CHECK_NA_STRING([dict objectForKey:@"ADDRESS_A"]));  // nothing empty string
NSLog(@"%d",[CHECK_NA_STRING([dict objectForKey:@"ADDRESS_A"]) length]); // return 1
```

Nothing will print for the first NSLOG, but the second will print a "1".  Indeed the string is one character long; it just messes up your NSLOG.

You probably want to test for some valid range of responses, or some invalid range.  Perhaps, you could use a regular expression.